# How can one plot a sum in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, summation

I would like to plot the following answer to the heat equation,

```
Sum[(((-1)^n - 1)/n^2) Cos[n x] Exp[-(n^2 t)], x]
```

But since it is a sum, it does not appear to work.

I define

```
v[x_,t_]=Sum[(((-1)^n - 1)/n^2) Cos[n x] Exp[-(n^2 t)], x]
```

Then I do

```
Plot3D[v[x,t], {t, -5, 5}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

But I get a blank plot, with only the axes shown.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are three unknowns `n`, `x` and `t` in your formula

Comment: Hi @Vangsnes, address the comment by Richardo and also see the syntax of `Sum`. Your function `v` will be evaluated by `Plot3D` for real arguments and will expect a numerical value as output. i.e `v[1,1]` should evaluate to a number, whit it doesn't.

Comment: Even terms are zero. `nmax = 20; Sum[(((-1)^n - 1)/n^2) Cos[n x] Exp[-(n^2 t)], {n, 1, nmax}] == Sum[-2/n^2 Cos[n x] Exp[-(n^2 t)], {n, 1, nmax, 2}] == Sum[-2/(2 n - 1)^2 Cos[(2 n - 1) x] Exp[-((2 n - 1)^2 t)], {n, 1, Ceiling[nmax/2]}]`

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following. I am assuming your sum starts from $n=1$ else you will get division by zero for $n=0$. If you want more accuracy, increase the number of terms in the sum.

[image]

```
ClearAll[x,t,n,v];
v[x_, t_, maxTerms_] := Sum[(((-1)^n - 1)/n^2) Cos[n*x] Exp[-(n^2 *t)], {n, 1, maxTerms}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[v[x, t, 5] /. t -> t0, {x, 0, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2.5, 2.5}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Time ", t0, " seconds"}]],
 {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, 3, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t0}
 ]
```

If you want 3D

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[v[x, t, 10], {x, 0, 3}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Time ", tmax, " seconds"}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "time", "u(x,t)"}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 4}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"],
 {{tmax, .01, "time"}, 0.01, 4, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tmax}
 ]
```